# Add Pagination to wp-query

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to add a pagination to my post query.

I tried all the samples i found in the internet to add a pagination without any success :/

This is my query code with the pagination code I tried:

```
            <?php

          $count = 0;

          // Query Code

          $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

          $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'category_name' => 'Recognitions', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged));

          if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) :
              while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post();
              ?>

              <?php $linktab = 'http://' . "localhost:8888/Lemon/wordpress/?page_id=158" ."&featuredimage=".get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>

                      <div class="wraper-tab
                      <?php

                      $count++;

                      $current_image = $_GET["featuredimage"];

                      if (!isset($current_image) && $count == 1) {
                        $_GET["featuredimage"] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
                        $current_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
                      }

                      if ($current_image == get_the_post_thumbnail_url()) {
                        echo "active";
                      }

                       ?>
                      ">

                      <a class="mitch-button to-load dark" href="<?php echo $linktab ?>" data-i="1" data-title="Lapka">
                        <article class="tab vertical-center" data-background-l="dark" data-background-p="dark" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
                            <header class="page-header caption">
                                <div>
                                    <h6 class="tab-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></h6>
                                      <h2 class="title" itemprop="name"><?php the_title(); echo $count;?></h2>
                                </div>
                            </header>
                            <div class="media">
                                <img src="" />
                            </div>

                        </article>
                        </a>
                      </div>

              <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php
          else :
              _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
          endif;
        ?>
      </div>

      <?php
      // Pagination code
      next_posts_link();
      previous_posts_link();
       ?>
```

I want to make so that it shows 3 posts per page. thats why I added 3 in the `posts_per_page` parameter.

I want a numbered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code

```
<?php $count = 0; $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'category_name' => 'Recognitions', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>3, 'paged' => $paged )); $wpb_all_query->query_vars[ 'paged' ] > 1 ? $current = $wpb_all_query->query_vars[ 'paged' ] : $current = 1; 
$pagination = array(
       'base' => 'page/%#%',
       //'format' => '',
       'showall' => false,
       'end_size' => 1,
       'mid_size' => 6,
       'total' => $wpb_all_query->max_num_pages,
       'current' => $current,
       'prev_text' => __('&larr;'),
        'next_text' => __('&rarr;'),
       'type' => 'list'
   );
     $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
   $url = str_replace('&page='.$current, '', $actual_link);
  global $wp_rewrite;
  if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
    $pagination[ 'base' ] =  $url. '&page=%#%' ;
      if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) :
          while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post();
          ?>
          <?php $linktab = 'http://' . "localhost:8888/Lemon/wordpress/?page_id=158" ."&featuredimage=".get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>
                  <div class="wraper-tab
                  <?php
                  $count++;
                 $current_image = $_GET["featuredimage"];
                  if (!isset($current_image) && $count == 1) {
                    $_GET["featuredimage"] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
                    $current_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
                  }
                  if ($current_image == get_the_post_thumbnail_url()) {
                    echo "active";
                  }
                   ?>
                  ">
                  <a class="mitch-button to-load dark" href="<?php echo $linktab ?>" data-i="1" data-title="Lapka">
                    <article class="tab vertical-center" data-background-l="dark" data-background-p="dark" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
                        <header class="page-header caption">
                            <div>
                                <h6 class="tab-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></h6>
                                  <h2 class="title" itemprop="name"><?php the_title(); echo $count;?></h2>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="" />
                        </div>

                    </article>
                    </a>
                  </div>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
           <?php
      else :
          _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
      endif;
    ?>
  </div><nav class="woocommerce-pagination"><?php echo paginate_links($pagination); ?></nav>
```

Comment: Savior! im getting the pagination now but the second's page link is : https://page/2?... :/

Comment: I tired changing the parameter "page" without being able to fix it :/

Comment: note that this is a normal page where I added this code and not a category page

Comment: how can i make it so that the url of the pagination is : http://localhost:8888/Lemon/wordpress/?page_id=158&paged=2                                http://localhost:8888/Lemon/wordpress/?page_id=158&paged=3  etc?                        If its possible to replace the first part of the url with a global variable, that would be helpful

Comment: you want URL like this localhost:8888/Lemon/wordpress/?page_id=158&paged=2 ?